# Ubuntu stuck at wallpaper after login

Tags: login

Hi guys I got problem when I login on my main user, it gets stucked at wallpaper. But when I login on guest user or make new user It works fine. Is there anyway to fix this.
I use ubuntu 14.04 and Toshiba Satellite c660.

Answer (score -1):

I removed:  .ICEAuthority and  .Xauthority and it worked.